# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro en una web con PHP?

Tags: php, html, filtro

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de tienda virtual con PHP y HTML en el que quiero poner un filtro con el que ordenar los productos en base al precio y al orden alfabético de los productos. Tengo el siguiente código (he quitado cosas que no interesan para lo que quiero hacer, como el menú o el footer):

```
<div class="productos">
<section class="ordenar">
    <h3>Ordenar por:
            <select name="id_producto">
                <option value="1">Orden alfabético (A-Z)</option>
                <option value="2">Orden alfabético inverso (Z-A)</option>
                <option value="3">Precio más bajo a más alto</option>
                <option value="4">Precio más alto a más bajo</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Aplicar</button>
    </h3>
</section>

<div class="mostrar_productos>
    <?php 
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario_BD, $contrasena_BD, $basedatos);
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
        $peticion = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE categoria = 'cuerda'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion);

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            echo "<div class='col-md-3 producto_individual'>";
            $peticion2 = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id_producto = " .$fila["id_producto"] . " ";
            $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion2);

            echo "<h2>" . $fila['nombre_producto'] . "</h2>";
            echo "<img src='imagenes/" .$fila["imagen"] . "' width = 100px>";
            echo "<p>" . $fila['descripcion_corta'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>Precio: " . $fila['precio'] . " €</p>";
            echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='producto_individual.php?id_producto=" .$fila["id_producto"]. "'><strong>Ver más</strong></a></p></div>";

        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>              
 </div>
```

Entonces, mi pregunta es cuál exactamente es el código PHP que tengo que usar para que al seleccionar la opción que quiero en el select option me aplique las acciones que le indico. Sé que la consulta a la base de datos sería con "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY nombre_producto/precio ASC/DESC", pero es que llevo un par de días intentando hacerlo y dando vueltas y es que no sé cómo ponerlo para que me saque los productos así y tengo ya un bloqueo mental importante. Seguro que es una cosa tontísima, pero caigo en cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Yo cambiara el planteamiento y usaría una clase ya sea productos con sus get y set y luego otro con sus funciones. Podrás de este modo saber la info de cada producto y pasarle su id para poder obtener ese producto. $producto->getId()

Comment: Tenes un error en la linea <div class="mostrar_productos> te falto cerrar la clase con la comilla doble

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunas correcciones al script. Espero te funcione.

```
<div class="productos">
<section class="ordenar">
    <h3>Ordenar por:
           <form method="POST">  <!--  AGREGE LA ETIQUETA FORM -->

                <select name="id_producto">
                    <option value="1">Orden alfabético (A-Z)</option>
                    <option value="2">Orden alfabético inverso (Z-A)</option>
                    <option value="3">Precio más bajo a más alto</option>
                    <option value="4">Precio más alto a más bajo</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Aplicar</button>

            </form>  <!--  AGREGE LA ETIQUETA FIN FORM -->
    </h3>
</section>
<!--div -->



 <div class="mostrar_productos">  <!--  CERRE LA COMILLA DE LA class -->
    <?php 
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario_BD, $contrasena_BD, $basedatos);
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

            /*  Agregue tipo de listado de acuerdo al Select  */
            if( !isset($_POST['id_producto']) ){
                  $peticion = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE categoria = 'cuerda'";
                }else{
                    if ( $_POST['id_producto'] == "1" ){
                        $peticion = "SELECT * FROM producto  order by nombre_producto asc";
                    }
                    if ( $_POST['id_producto'] == "2" ){
                        $peticion = "SELECT * FROM producto  order by nombre_producto desc";
                    }
                    if ( $_POST['id_producto'] == "3" ){
                        $peticion = "SELECT * FROM producto  order by precio asc";
                    }
                    if ( $_POST['id_producto'] == "4" ){
                        $peticion = "SELECT * FROM producto  order by precio desc";
                    }
                }


        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion);

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            echo "<div class='col-md-3 producto_individual'>";
            $peticion2 = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id_producto = " .$fila["id_producto"] . " ";
            $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion2);

            echo "<h2>" . $fila['nombre_producto'] . "</h2>";
            echo "<img src='imagenes/" .$fila["imagen"] . "' width = 100px>";
            echo "<p>" . $fila['descripcion_corta'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>Precio: " . $fila['precio'] . " €</p>";
            echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='producto_individual.php?id_producto=" .$fila["id_producto"]. "'><strong>Ver más</strong></a></p></div>";

        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>              
 </div>
```

Comment: ¡Funciona! Lo único es que en los if te ha faltado poner el "WHERE categoria = 'cuerda'", porque si no saca todos los productos. Muchas gracias ^-^